# File not found error - trying to convert symlinks to regular files

Tags: shell, symlink

I am trying to convert symlinks to hardlinks. I have the line in my script:

```
find -type l -exec -c 'ln -f "$(readlink -m "$0")" "$0"' {} \;
```

But I get the following error:

```
FIND: Parameter format not correct
File not found - -TYPE
File not found - L
File not found - -EXEC
File not found - -C
File not found - LN -F \$(READLINK
File not found - -M
Access denied - \
File not found - $0\)\
File not found -  \$0\
File not found - {}
File not found - ;
```

I am not able to figure out what went wrong. Please help!

Comment: You're not passing a path to find, I'm assuming you meant `find . -type l ...`

Comment: Hi, I did that too but it said 
File not found . 
 :|

Comment: By any chance, are you running this command in windows command prompt? The unix find command is different than windows find command.